# Unable to cd into htdocs when I use the command line

Tags: bash, command-line

I created an alias for the htdocs folder. I named it sites and put it on the desktop. When I try to cd into it when I use the command line I receive this message.

```
-bash: cd: sites: Not a directory
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -l sites`?

Comment: I think it is what it is. "sites" is just not a directory. Do as Tim says.

Comment: @Tim Zimmerman when I try ls -l sites I get this msg:    `-rw-r--r--@ 1 davidcastillo  staff  1938768 Oct 20 19:10 sites`

Comment: `sites` is not a directory; it's a file that's 1938768 bytes in size. How exactly did you "create an alias"?

Comment: In the MAMPS folder in applications , I right click on htdocs then click on make alias.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out .I'm new to the command line and I didn't know I could just drag a folder to the command line to manipulate it. Also realized I could access content of the application folder with:
    `cd /applications/{name of file}`